# How to get Last 6 Month data comparing with timestamp column using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to display catches, monthname and monthvalue from past 6 months including current month , if any month don't have any catches just display monthname and 0 value for ex:

data:

```
[
    {
      "monthText": "May",
      "monthInt": 5,
      "Catches": 10
    },
    {
      "monthText": "April",
      "monthInt": 4,
      "Catches": 12
    },
   {
      "monthText": "June",
      "monthInt": 6,
      "Catches": 0
    }

]
```

I have query

```
SELECT COUNT(CaughtId) as catches, MONTH(DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())) AS MonthValue ,LEFT(DATENAME(mm,  DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())), 3) AS MonthText FROM [dbo].[Catches] fct WHERE fct.[TripId] IN
    (SELECT TripId FROM [dbo].[Trips] WHERE UserId = 'e406d452-3755-4dbb-99a9-1f01df60d842')
    AND fct.Timestamp >= dateadd(month,-6,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),1))
```

with above query I am getting below output

```
catch   monthvalue   monthname
20         12           Dec
```

Comment: To do so you need to join with some table where all the months you want to create are present, so you can perform a left join operation against this table in order to show 0 when the month doesn't have data

Comment: I don't see no JSON related function in your query, so I guess you have the data plainly in a table. So please don't post it as JSON, use `INSERT INTO` statements to display table data (along with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables).

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this query:

```
with dates as (
  select dateadd(month,-5,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,getdate(),112),112)) as datefield
  union all
  select dateadd(month,1,datefield) from dates
  where datefield + 1 <= convert(datetime,convert(varchar,getdate(),112),112)
  )  
,your_data as (
  select 5 as mnt,  10 as catches union all
  select 4 as mnt,  12 as catches union all
  select 6 as mnt,  0 as catches
  )
select datename(month,d.datefield) as MonthName,
  month(d.datefield) as MonthNumber,
  isnull(yd.catches,0) as catches
from dates d
  left join your_data yd
    on month(d.datefield)=yd.mnt
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Output:

[image]